# Manipulating IPv6 Addresses in Java

Tags: java, ip, ipv6, inetaddress

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a specific answer which seems to work. I am basically trying to write a function which will take an IPv6 address and add or subtract an arbitrary number of IP addresses to it.

I think I am hitting an issue with byte ordering as it works for some IPv6 addresses but not for others. However, I need some help in trying to work out the problem as I am stuck.

I have provided an SSCCE below which demonstrates the problem - it basically converts from an InetAddress to a BigInteger and back again - the idea is to perform the addition or subtraction from the BigInteger in the middle:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SSCCE {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sIPv6 = "::00D3:0:2F3B:02AA:00FF:0";

    try {
      BigInteger n = new BigInteger(InetAddress.getByName(sIPv6).getAddress());
      byte[] bytes = n.toByteArray();

      System.out.println("Original = " + sIPv6);
      System.out.println("New = " + InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes).getHostAddress());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Original = ::00D3:0:2F3B:02AA:00FF:0
java.net.UnknownHostException: addr is of illegal length
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(Unknown Source)
        at SSCCE.main(SSCCE.java:12)
```

However, if I change the IPv6 address to "2001::00D3:0:2F3B:02AA:00FF:0" then it works fine.

Comment: see if your program likes '2001:0:d3:0:2f3b:2aa:ff:0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
  BigInteger n = new BigInteger(InetAddress.getByName(sIPv6).getAddress());
  byte[] bytes = n.toByteArray();
```

When you invoke `toByteArray()` the returned array is only large enough to contain all the significant bits of the address.  Since your address starts with `0:0:...` the returned byte array will be too short (14). You must left-pad it with binary zeros to make it 128 bits long (16 bytes).

Comment: Yep, you are right. If I check the length it is 14 instead of 16. Is there an easy way to pad it to 16? - I have tried to use `Arrays.copyOf(n, 16)` but this pads it at the end. I am assuming I need to create a byte array of length 16 and copy into it? Any pointers?

Comment: I have come up with the following but not sure if there is an easier way using a single Java function?       byte[] pbytes = new byte[16];
      int offset = (16 - bytes.length);

      for (int i = offset; i < 16; i++) {
        pbytes[i] = bytes[i - offset];
      }

Comment: Use `java.lang.System#arraycopy()` instead of writing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but not complete.  In addition to the left-padding described, you must also occasionally delete the highest byte when you have 17 bytes, which can occur for addresses with 8xxx to fxxx in the highest byte, as described in this answer: [IPv6 ip (fc00::) addr is of illegal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222896/ipv6-ip-fc00-addr-is-of-illegal-length/39406078#39406078)

In other words, you must either expand or shrink to exactly 16 bytes.